# How to output this lines of text to a JDialog in Java?

Tags: java, file, text, jdialog

Basically my dialog has 2 JTextFields. One for Name and another for age.
It has a group of Radio Buttons. Male and Female.
And a checkbox for Single, Married, Widowed, and Separated.
A Load, Save, Append, Prev, Next, and Load File button.

And then I saved and appended lines of texts into a text file:
Joshua Chiu,18,M,M
Heidi Chiu,16,F,S
Noel Gunay,45,M,M
Monster,22,F,W

If I press my Load button, it would open the file I selected (in this case, joshua.txt). And what happens is that the infos Joshua Chiu will fill the Name text field, 18 will fill the age text field, Male button will be selected, and Married checkbox is selected.

Now, I need a code for my Prev and Next buttons, that in which I press Next, it will output the next line's info on the dialog, (Heidi Chiu, 16, Female, Single), and that if I press Prev, it will fill the info of the dialog.

I'm sorry I don't have a picture which could have made this post easier to understand.

Comment: Load the contents of each line to something like an `ArrayList`, maintain an index of your current position within the `ArrayList`, update the content based on the current index, based on the direction of movement

Comment: Hmm. That was what I was thinking of too. But my problem is that I don't know how to put it into a code.